# python loop function in cs

Tags: python, c#

description: Python can loop functions in eachother. can cS loop function too?

Example python:

```
def func():
   x=input(">")
   func()
```

Example c# ***expected***:

```
namespace f
{class f{
   static void main(string[] args){
      void stuff() {
         Console.readLine()
         stuff()
      }
   }
}}
```

i dont think its possible to loop function in the function in cs.

what i mean by looping function is by putting the void inside the container. here is what i mean ***python***:

```
def g():
   x=input(">")
   g()
```

output (typer):

```
Python Latest Update
>h
>bruh
>new line
>new new line
>line
>infinite input lines
> repeating function
```

i use this because in python i added commands in the script and i do it so i wont need to retype until the python stops the input.

example:

```
Problem (python script):
def func():
   x=input(">")
   if x=="help":
      print("commands: help")
      x=input(">")
      if x=="help":
         #repeat

Solution (python script):
def func():
   x=input(">")
   if x=="help":
      print("commands: help")
      func()
```

why i put the examples in python script: idk if you can do this in c# so im not going to confuse anyone

Can this happen in C#?

Comment: Warning to people who flag as less descriptive/clarity: i put all the details i can.

Comment: What you're talking about here is "recursion". and what you are doing is a very bad example of recursion.  You should NOT use recursion for this kind of looping.  Every function call creates another stack frame, over and over, using up memory.  Yes, of course C# supports recursion, but in these cases you should be using loops.

Comment: im making a cmd-like exe file. does that reproduse too?

Comment: It doesn't matter what the application is.  You should be looping here, not using recursion.  Recursion is helpful for mathematical functions and nested algorithms, but this is not such a case.

Comment: how to loop? just answer with "i recommend you to loop" ans write because i dk how to loop

Comment: In Python, it's `while True:`.  In C#, it's `while( 1 ) {`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249714/discussion-between-jxon-and-tim-roberts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with C# but hopefully this page can help [Recursive Function C#](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/955025/C-Sharp-interview-questions-part4what-is-a-recursive-function-in/)

What you're trying to make is called a recursive function

Comment: thanks im giving you alot of reputation

Answer (score 1):

Every modern language supports recursion.  The problem in your example was you had a nested function, which C# doesn't do.  You'd write it like this:

```
namespace f {
  class f{
    static void stuff() {
      Console.readLine();
      stuff();
    }
    static void main(string[] args){
      stuff();
    }
  }
}
```

But I want to reiterate that this is poor practice.  There are some languages in which the compiler can catch this "tail recursion" and optimize for it, turning it into a "jump" that doesn't use stack space.  Python and C# do not do that.

The proper way is just:

```
namespace f {
  class f{
    static void stuff() {
      while( 1 ) {
        Console.readLine();
      }
    }
    static void main(string[] args){
      stuff();
    }
  }
}
```

Ordinarily, you would have some condition inside the loop signalling it was time to end, and you'd do a `break` to stop the loop.

Comment: can we do a if statement like while(if (x=="help")) or while(x=="help") {print("commands: help")}

Comment: im making a command prompt

Comment: Actually, C# does (unfortunately) allow you to declare functions within functions. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions